# How to access data sent in postMessage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I need to run JavaScript inside iFrame, I understand that I must use post message to do this but I do not understand how to use it.

Site 1 is `http://www.example.com/chat.html`
Site 2 (iFrame on Site 1) is `http://www.example.com:7778`

**Site**

```
$( "#link" ).click(function() {
    document.getElementById('iframe_id_here').contentWindow.postMessage({command: 'joinChannel', args: {channel: $(this).attr('data-room')}}, '*');
});
```

**iFrame**

```
function joinChannel(event)
{
  if (event.origin !== "http://example.com/chat.html")
    return;

  network.join(***How do I access $(this).attr('data-room')?***, '');
}

window.addEventListener("message", joinChannel, false);
```

Comment: you may want to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/364952/4340788) question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663242/calling-a-function-inside-an-iframe-from-outside-the-iframe too.

Comment: Why do you have them on different ports? You can't just use the same domain and port?

Comment: @FezVrasta — No. `postMessage` doesn't require anything special on the server. Its permissions are specified in the JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

In [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), the passed message is stored in the `event.data` object.

In your case, the channel should be accessible via `event.data.args.channel`.